# Understanding Docker volumes

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am trying to learn Docker volumes, and I am using `centos:latest` as my base image. When I try to run a Docker command, I am unable to access the attached volume inside the container:

Command:

```
sudo docker run -it --name test -v /home/user/Myhostdir:/mydata centos:latest /bin/bash
```

Error:

```
[user@0bd1bb78b1a5 mydata]$ ls
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
```

When I try to `ls` to find the folder permission, it says 1001. What's happening, and how can to solve this?

```
drwxrwxr-x.   2 1001 1001    38 Jun  2 23:12 mydata
```

My local machine:

```
[user@xxx07012 Myhostdir]$ pwd
/home/user/Myhostdir
[user@swathi07012 Myhostdir]$ ls -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x.  2 user user   38 Jun  2 23:12 .
drwx------. 18 user user 4096 Jun  2 23:11 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user user   15 Jun  2 23:12 text.2.txt
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user user   25 Jun  2 23:12 text.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partially a Docker issue, but mostly an [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) issue. I am assuming you are running an old `1.x` version of Docker.

You have a couple of options. First, you could take a look at [this blog post](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/) to understand the issue a bit more and possibly use the fix mentioned there.

Or you could just upgrade to a newer version of Docker. I tested mounting a simple volume on Docker version 18.03.1-ce:

```
docker run -it --name test -v /home/chris/test:/mydata centos:latest /bin/bash

[root@bfec7af20b99 /]# cd mydata/
[root@bfec7af20b99 mydata]# ls
test.txt.txt
[root@bfec7af20b99 mydata]# ls -l
total 0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jun  3 00:40 test.txt.txt
```